# Move an image with an Angular Directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to move between two div an image when the screen gets smaller using a directive in Angular. 
With the following directive I can change the content of the one line when the screen get smaller/higher. But I can't do it with the image. I'd like to move that image from div 'before' to div 'then'. How can I do?
Link to Code: http://plnkr.co/edit/wd3M629xA5lnRymwbO3e

Directive code:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.name = 'World';
});

app.directive('browseContent', function($window) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div ng-include="templateUrl"></div>',
    link: function(scope) {

        $window.onresize = function() {
            changeTemplate();
            scope.$apply();
        };
        changeTemplate();

        function changeTemplate() {
            var screenWidth = $window.innerWidth;
            if (screenWidth < 768) {
                scope.templateUrl = 'browse-content-mobile.html';
            } else if (screenWidth >= 768) {
                scope.templateUrl = 'browse-content.html';
            }
        }
    }
}
});
```